# Do event upon text being entered

Tags: tkinter

i am using tkinter in python and would like to add an event to an Entry widget.
I would like it to wait for text to be typed into it and then perform the action when text is typed.

something to the effect of:

```
self.entry(command=self.event)
```

is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Can you clarify  your question? Are you wanting something to happen on every keypress, only when the user presses the enter key, when the focus leaves the widget, or something else? All of those are possible, we just need to know what it is you really want.

Comment: Please clarify your question before it is closed...!!!! Be clear about what you want and don't speak in masked terms. Tell exactly what your requirements are and what homework you have done.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify how do you decide that the user has finished typing. You can:

- **Use timeout** - check how much time has passed between two letters and process input if the delay is longer than, say 3 seconds. Your typical user will not like this solution, but it would seem that is what you are after. The way to do this:

  1. "define" your StringVar: `s = Tkinter.StringVar(root)`
  2. [assign callback](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) for writing to your StringVar: `s.trace('w', handle_input)`
  3. handle delay checking and useful code in your *handle_input* callback
  4. when creating Entry widget, pass in your StringVar as textvariable: `e = Tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable=s)`
- **Use enter key when finished typing** - [bind](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) `"<Enter>"` event to Entry widget:

  ```
  e.bind('<Enter>', handle_input)
  ```